# python3: find most k nearest vectors from a list?

Tags: python-3.x

Say I have a vector `v1` and a list of vector `l1`. I want to find `k` vectors from `l1` that are most closed (similar) to `v1` in descending order.

I have a function `sim_score(v1,v2)` that will return a similarity score between 0 and 1 for any two input vectors.

Indeed, a naive way is to write a `for` loop over `l1`, calculate distance and store them into another list, then sort the output list. But is there a Pythonic way to do the task?

Thanks

Comment: Among the K nearest items, does order matter?

Comment: yes, I want to sort them in descending order, i.e. from the most closed vector in ``l1``

Comment: Then you will have no choice but to iterate over each pair, insert into a list, and then sort.

Comment: Consider using [scipy.spatial.distance](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/spatial.distance.html) module for distance computations.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

np.sort([np.sqrt(np.sum(( l-v1)*(l-v1))) For l in l1])[:3]
```

Comment: It is assuming your arrays are numpy arrays and I have used list comprehension.

Comment: Did you try running it?

Comment: It is usually not a good idea to build loops around numpy arrays, since you eliminate the speed up gained by vectorization. `np.sort(np.sqrt(np.sum((v1-l1)**2, axis=1)))` is equivalent but much faster.

Comment: This is nice.forgot about numpy arrays broadcasting future which is very handy

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [scipy.spatial.distance](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/spatial.distance.html) module for distance computations. It supports the most common metrics.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import distance


v1 = [[1, 2, 3]]

l1 = [[11, 3, 5], 
      [ 2, 1, 9], 
      [.1, 3, 2]]

# compute distances
dists = distance.cdist(v1, l1, metric='euclidean')

# sorted distances
sd = np.sort(dists)
```

Note that each parameter to `cdist` must be two-dimensional. Hence, `v1` must be a nested list, or a 2d numpy array.

You may also use your homegrown metric like:

```
def my_metric(a, b, **kwargs):
    # some logic


dists = distance.cdist(v1, l1, metric=my_metric)
```